# Buffering an input parameter to the process statement

Tags: vhdl, fpga

Take the following code for example:

```
s_Clock_Data <= pi_Clock_Data;

Shifter :
process(s_Clock_Data)
begin
    if falling_edge(s_Clock_Data) then
        s_Shifter <= s_Shifter(s_Shifter'high - 1 downto 0) & pi_Data;
    end if;
end process;
```

Where pi_Clock_Data and pi_Data are port inputs to the module.

Is there a certain reason that requires pi_Clock_Data to be first assigned to s_Clock_Data before the process can run?  Since pi_Data is also an input to the fpga, it seems that by doing this, the clock data could be lagging behind by a delta cycle with respect to pi_Data.

Couldn't we just have
process(pi_Clock_Data)
instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reassigning the clock should be avoided, due to the reason of delta cycle delay that you describe.

It will have no effect on the synthesis result, but it is likely to cause problems in simulation, for example if several nested modules does reassigning of the clock, whereby the clock can end up being delayed by numerous delta delays, but the related data may not have similar delta delay, whereby the design will not simulate as the expected synchronous design.

The image below show what happens, where `clk` updates `cnt`, `clk` is also used to capture `cnt` to `cap_clk`, and `clk` is then reassigned as:

```
clk_delta_1 <= clk;
```

and `clk_delta_1` is then used to capture `cnt` to `cap_delta_1`.  The result is that `cap_clk` and `cap_delta_1` does not capture the same values in simulation.

[image]

However, in the synthesized design, the `clk_delta_1 <= clk;` will be a plain wire, so `cap_delta_1` will capture based on `clk`, so simulation and synthesis result will not be the same for the design in this case, which is the reason reassigning clocks should be avoided.

If for some reason a renaming of the signal is required, then an alias can be used, thus making a new name for `clk` without a delta delay, like:

```
alias clk_delta_0 : std_logic is clk;
```

As the figure shows, then `cnt` captured on `clk_delta_0` to `cap_delta_0` will have the same values as the `cap_clk`, since there is no delta delay between `clk` and `clk_delta_0`.  However, such renaming should be avoided if possible, since it makes reading the searching the code difficult.